# Can you get 240 volts and 50 amps from paralleled inverter generators?

Tags: power-supply, inverter, high-voltage, generator, high-current

I'm here for help solving the problem of suppling a 240v, 45amp kiln off the grid. The catch is, we can't just use a large portable generator. So,

-can you put three or more inverter generators in parallel?

-can you get 240 volts out of paralleled 120volt inverter generators? Is there equipment that can do this? (transformer?)

-can you put inverter generators into series to raise voltage?

-how would ***you*** supply 240volts and 50amps of power off grid if you couldn't use without a large portable generator?

Any ideas/suggests welcome.

Comment: You need a method to synchronize them, which will not be cheap.

Comment: Yes, you can parallel inverters, but it's not trivial. If doing something involving a kiln off-grid, give some thought to using actual fire instead of electricity for it.

Comment: Some Honda generators come with this feature. Don’t know if they scale all the way up to 50 A though.

Comment: Some models of Honda's inverter generators can be paralleled - but I don't think you can get 50 Amps - don't know about 240 volts, either.

Comment: A typical 11kW hobby ceramic kiln is not a very suitable load for inverters- too many kW and it has to operate for many hours. Maybe the best solution is to buy a small trailer and haul it into town to plug it into the grid when needed.

Comment: Is it a single heating element or a multiple that could each be run from a separate supply?

Answer (score 2):

Consider a large propane fired burner as the main heat flux, then drop the  electric needs to just temperature regulation.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use a gas operated kiln? With some modifications you might be able to rectify the AC to DC, so it would be easier to run generators in parallel to heat a resistive load. With AC you would have to synchronize frequency and phase.

Comment: I generally consider "off grid" to mean no connection to the electric *or* gas utilities, but if that's not the case this is a good answer too.

Comment: True, I guess it often means that you don't want to depend on consumables like gas bottles, so you'd have to produce the gas yourself. In temporary situation a ~10 kg gas bottle will you get you pretty far.